# Arduino+processing and string information in an "if" statment

Tags: string, if-statement, arduino, processing

I am using an arduino to read out information from a scale into Processing. 
Now I want certain things to happen depending on the weight registered. The weight is read out in a String. I have found out that `>=` does not work for strings. I have tried `if (val >= str ("20.00"))` but that doesnt work either.

I have also tried to convert it into a float using `float scale = Float.parseFloat(val);` But that doesnt work either. Does anyone have an idea. That would be great!

```
PImage pictureday;
import processing.serial.*;
import cc.arduino.*;
import org.firmata.*;

Serial myPort;  
String val;     
color textcolor = color(0, 50, 50, 240);
color textcolor2 = color(255, 0, 0); 

void setup()
{
  fullScreen();
  background (189, 215, 239);
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); 
  } 

  if (scale >= 20.00)
  { 
    image(pictureday, 0, 0);  
    textSize(50);
    fill(textcolor);
    text(val, 900, 360);
    text("KG ", 1030, 360);  
    println (val);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that Float.parseFloat() doesn't work? How exactly are you using it? Also, try getting rid of all the Arduino stuff and posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead. Use hardcoded values that match what you're getting from Arduino.

Comment: I have tried like this: Serial myPort;
String val;    
void setup()
{  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}
void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); // read it and store it in val
  } 
  float scale = float(val);
  if (scale >= 0)
  { 
    image(pictureday, 0, 0);  
    textSize(50);
    fill(textcolor);
    text(scale, 900, 360);
    text("KG ", 1030, 360);  
    println (scale);
  }
}

Comment: and also like this: Serial myPort;
String val;    
void setup()
{  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}
void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); // read it and store it in val
  } 
float scale = Float.parseFloat(val);
  if (scale >= 0)
  { 
    image(pictureday, 0, 0);  
    textSize(50);
    fill(textcolor);
    text(scale, 900, 360);
    text("KG ", 1030, 360);  
    println (scale);
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Like you've discovered, you can't compare Strings like that. Processing isn't smart enough to know the String contains a number.

Instead, use the [float()](https://www.processing.org/reference/floatconvert_.html) function:

```
String val = "123.456";
float f = float(val);
if(f > 100){
   println("here!");
}
```

Comment: I tried to do both "float scale = float(val);" and "float scale = Float.parseFloat(val);" but neither are working it says "Could not run sketch" now

Comment: @sobren15 Edit your question to include the `float()` code you've tried, as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Take out the Arduino stuff and just use a hardcoded String.

Comment: @ Kevin Workman, I thought I did that on your comment/question?

Comment: @sobren15 Your comment does not say **where** in your sketch you added that code. And I can't run your sketch since it contains Arduino logic, which doesn't have anything to do with your question. It'll be easier to talk about your code if you post it all in once place, in a way that I can run it.

Comment: Im sorry, I am kind o new to this.  But since it is importing sensor data from Arduino, I do not understand how I should remove that from the code. I wrote it in my void draw:void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); 
  } 
float scale = Float.parseFloat(val);
  if (scale >= 0) { etc...

Comment: @sobren15 Like my example, hardcode a String. All you're asking about is converting a String to a float, so that's all your code should contain. Edit your question so your code can be run by other people, and you'll have much better luck getting help.